# Checking size of XML attachments encoded in base64

Tags: c#, xml

I'm iterating through a list with many XML files, each one of them has attached various files in it, encoded in base64. Template of attachments:

```
        <my:Attachments>
        <my:Attachment-name>base64code</my:Attachment-name>
        <my:Attachment-name-Description/>
        <my:Attachment-name2>base64code</my:Attachment-name2>
        <my:Attachment-Checklist-Description/>
        <my:Additional-Attachments>
            <my:Attachment>base64code</my:Attachment>
            <my:Attachment-Description>description</my:Attachment-Description>
        </my:Additional-Attachments>
        <my:Additional-Attachments>
            <my:Attachment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">base64code</my:Attachment>
            <my:Attachment-Description>description2</my:Attachment-Description>
        </my:Additional-Attachments>
    </my:Attachments>
```

My goal is to check a number of attachments across all files and number of attachments with size bigger than provided.

I'm doing it in c# and I'm stuck on digging into xml files itself. Any suggestions how can I iterate through those attachments coded into xml, and check their size while they are in base64?

**Update:**

As per suggestion of daniell89 i did this:

```
                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in fileCollection)
                {
                    FileInformation fileInformation =
                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileInformation.Stream))
                    {
                        XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(streamReader);
                        XNamespace my =
                            XNamespace.Get(
                                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-05-03T19:16:34");

                        foreach (XElement xe in xmlDocument.Descendants(my + "Attachments"))
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Since each of the elements in attachments node has different name, I'm trying to iterate through all of them and if its value has base64, then do the rest. The problem is that instead of a collection with each of the rows, i get 1 item consisting of all rows in my:Attachments

Comment: There are a *lot* of tutorials on working with XML with C# online.

Comment: The XDocument class in the System.Xml.Linq namespace allows for easy manage and manipulation of XML using LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XDocument class and Linq to xml. Here is an example:

```
string xmlData = "yourXmlString";
int maxAttachementSize = 100000;
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
XNamespace my_ns = "myNamespaceDefinition";
var attachementsInBase64String = xml.Descendants(my_ns + "Attachment").Select(x => x.Value);
var tooBigAttachements = attachementsInBase64String .Where(att => Convert.FromBase64String(att).Length > maxAttachementSize);
```

According to your update you can check attachements in this way (assuming that you have one Attachements element):

```
foreach (XElement xElem in xDoc.Element("Attachments").Descendants().Where(e => !e.HasElements))
{
      if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xElem.Value))
      {
           byte[] attachement = Convert.FromBase64String(xElem.Value);
           // rest of a code
      }
}
```

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object unfortunatelly on foreach. I have only 1 my:Attachments node, it looks like provided, and is in such a hierarchy: my:Main node > my:ProjectData node in it > and in that node rests my:Attachments

Comment: @Wolwgang, updated. Foreach loop should enumerate only through all leaves.